# Finding unique customers in a selected day range

Tags: database, algorithm, data-structures, druid

I have a simple table as follows:

```
day     order_id    customer_id
1       1           1
1       2           1
1       3           2
2       4           1
2       5           1
```

I want to find a number of unique customers from Day 1 to Day 2. And the answer is 2.

But my size of the table is huge and querying takes long. So I want to store an aggregated data in another table to reduce the data size and query faster. I have created a new table out of the above table.

```
day     uniq_customer
1       2
2       1
```

Now if I want to find a unique customer from Day 1 to Day 2, I am getting 2 + 1 = 3, whereas the answer is 2.

Is there any way to find a work around without having to query the old table.

PS: I am using Druid as a data source.

Answer (score 0):

This depends on the trends on your data. For example, if you have a small number of distinct customers and days, you can keep the customers in a bit vector per day. At the end, just `or` the bitvectors of the days in the query and the result will be the sum of the bits. May be boring to implement.

If you have a large number of distinct customers and days, chunk them per customer and sort by date. Then for each customer, get the index of first row where day is greater than or equal to the query start and get the index of the first row where day is less than or equal to the query end using binary search. Difference between those two indices plus 1 gives you the number-of-query-fitting-days for the customer. Complexity becomes #customers x 2 x O(log #customerRecords).

Answer (score 0):

Apache Druid supports the use of approximations for this kind of query. Take a look at the tutorial on using approximations in Druid: https://druid.apache.org/docs/latest/tutorials/tutorial-sketches-theta.html

In Druid you can also partially aggregate into Theta Sketches at ingestion time and aggregated them over time or over other grouping dimensions at query time. This is specifically designed to deal with large data volumes and you can control the accuracy of the approximations.